# Help Solving Multivariable Quintic Function

Tags: polynomials, multivariate-polynomial, quintics

I am developing a game, and I am working out some of the equations for one of the features of it. Essentially, I am adding a way for a character's skills to be inherited when they die, and this formula is a way to calculate what the new character's skill level will be.

I have defined the formula as follows:
$x = a + a d(b + Jc)$
Where:
$a$ is the current skill level of the character that died
$d$ is the potential loss over an inherited generation, and is defined as a random number in the range $-1 + Jc → 1$
$b$ is a base multiplier
$J$ is the number of characters that you have created - 1
$c$ is the additive gain for a player

Essentially, my goal is that I can configure a few base values and have the game calculate the value of $c$ dynamically. One important note here is that the goal of this function is to have a max value for the skills and $c$ would be a value, such that over a certain number of player deaths (say 6) the skill level would reach a maximum, assuming $d$ always rolls a 1. Here we will also assume that $b$ is a configurable value, and assume it is .1 in this case.

Therefore, I must substitute this formula 5 times over. For example:
$x_1 = 12$,
$x_2 = 12 + (12 \cdot 1)(0.1 + 1 \cdot c)$
$x_3 = (12 + (12 \cdot 1)(0.1 + 1 \cdot c)) + ((12 + (12 \cdot 1)(0.1 + 1 \cdot c))(.1 + 2c))$
repeat through to gen 6

The problem that I am having is solving for $c$ in terms of the other variables. For this it is safe to assume that $d$ is always 1, and in this case, it is also safe to assume that $J$ is 5.
I have managed to simplify the formula down to the following:
$$x_6 = a_1(5b^5c + 50b^4c^2 + 20b^4c + b^4 + 175b^3c^3\\
+ 150b^3c^2 + 35b^3c + b^3 + 250b^2c^4 + 350b^2c^3\\
+ 155b^2c^2 + 50b^2c + 9b^2 + 120bc^5 + 250bc^4\\
 + 185bc^3 + 130bc^2 + 34bc + 4b + 24c^4\\
 + 50c^3 + 27c^2 + 12c + 6)$$

However, I am not exactly the best at math, so this is as far as I have been able to get.

How do I solve for $c$ in terms of the other variables?

Comment: The Jenkins-Traub algorithm is one of the go to black box root finding algorithms for polynomials of degree less than 20 or so.

Comment: Where does $0.1$ come from in your $x_2=12+(12\cdot 1)(0.1+c)$? Where does $J=5$ disappear in the same expression, that is why is it $0.1+c$ and not $0.1+5c$?

Comment: @RandyMarsh I have edited the question to hopefully make that a little more clear. The .1 is essentially an assumed value (i.e. it would be configured), and, per the definition of variables, J is equal to the number of characters minus 1. Therefore in generation 2, J is equal to 1. I stated that J is equal to 5 because the final equation that I am trying to solve is for generation 6. Hopefully that clears things up a bit.

Comment: My first confusion is from not understanding how exactly you get $x_2$, $x_3$ etc. From the example you have given, you seem to have $x_1=a$ and then to get $x_2$ you substitute $x_1$ in place of $a$ in the formula $a+ad(b+Jc)$, where $J=1$. But then to get $x_3$ you substitute it in place of $x_2$ (that you've just calculated) in the formula $x_2+x_2d(b+Jc)$, but this time $J=2$. Is this correct?

Comment: My second confusion is about $J$. You define it as the number of characters that you have created $-1$. But from the example to me it seems that the more appropriate description of $J$ is the number of characters that have died so far, so at $x_1$ zero died, at $x_2$ one character died, at $x_3$ two characters died etc. Who exactly are the characters that we create, do the $J$ existing characters not count among the created characters?

Comment: To your first question: that is correct. a is basically the previous skill level, and x is the calculation of the skill level for the new character. So for the first character, I picked a random number as an example, and then plugged it in for $x_2$, then we take the results of $x_2$ and sub it in for $x_3$ and so forth all the way to $x_6$, each time J increasing by 1.

Comment: To your second question: your definition of the variable does seem to be more apt. So yes J essentially represents the number of characters that have died. The idea is that the game is going to be sort of season based, and that everyone who plays the game will die at the same time. So essentially, in one season everyone who plays the game might get a guaranteed 6 characters, depending how I balance it. Let me know if that didn't answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am interpreting this correctly, however you seem to have a recurrence relation
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}d(b+Jc),\quad a_1=12$$
which has the following solution:
$$a_n=12(1+bd+Jcd)^{n-1}$$
so $a_6=12(1+bd+Jcd)^5.$

Now I am not completely sure if you want to maximize $a_6$ with respect to some contstraints on $b$, $J$, $d$ and $c$, which amounts to maximizing $1+bd+Jcd$, or you want to find $c$ for a given value of $a_6$, $b$, $d$ and $J$, which in this case is
$$c=\frac1{Jd}\left(-1-bd+\sqrt[5]{\frac{a_6}{12}}\right)$$

More generally, if the value of $a_1$ is $A$, then $c=\frac1{Jd}\left(-1-bd+\sqrt[5]{\frac{a_6}{A}}\right)$.